# is document.getElementsByClassName faster than looping through the nodes?

Tags: javascript, html, select, getelementsbytagname, getelementsbyclassname

I am working on a script for a chrome extension for which I have to check if certain items exist in a division. And I am standing before a dilemma I am having. Let's say I first want to check for classnames, then for a tags with data-ng attributes and then for a img nested directly in an a tag. I could do this either by using:

```
var first = node.getElementsByClassName('classNameOfInterest');

var second = new Array();
var temp = node.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var a = 0 ; a < temp.length ; a++){
    if(temp[a].hasAttribute('data-ng')){
        second.push(temp[a]);
    }
}temp = false;

var third = new Array();
temp = node.getElementsByTagName('img');
for(var a = 0 ; a < temp.length ; a++){
    if(temp[a].parentNode.nodeName == 'A'){
        third.push(temp[a]);
    }
}temp = false;
```

or by going through all the elements of possible interest, and check them for the three conditions right away, like this:

```
var nodes = node.getElementsByTagName("*");
var first = new Array(); var second = first; var third = first;
for(var a = 0 ; a < nodes.length ; a++){
         if(nodes[a].className.match(\b(classNameOfInterest)\b))
             {first.push(nodes[a]);}
    else if(nodes[a].nodeName == 'A' && nodes[a].hasAttribute('data-ng'))
             {second.push(nodes[a]);}
    else if(nodes[a].nodeName == 'IMG' && nodes[a].parentNode.nodeName == 'A');
             {third.push(nodes[a]);}
}
```

---

Which of the methods is faster/better, and why? I want to make rational code ;). Please help!?

Comment: Try it in jsperf.com. Your node loop seems to neglect that class is a whitespace delimited token list. Also, you may get much better results using `document.querySelectorAll`

Comment: I could indeed try it. But i would love to get an explanation. Right now there are 3 conditions. But i am wondering what would happen if I had 15 conditions, or just 1. And i rather have a founded answer than having to write 2 code samples and testing them against each other with every step of the way.

Comment: Which method is better? `node.querySelectorAll("a.classNameOfInterest[data-ng] img")` is much cleaner

Comment: @Bergi That looks much cleaner indeed. But isn't that JQuery? And if not, it's just using selectors like we would in css? And if it is selecting the elements as we would in css, how would someone select the a tag in your example instead of the img tag? (since css doesnt have that abbility)

Comment: querySelectorAll doesn't return a live nodeList. Which is a major downside

Comment: Yes, it does use selectors like jQuery or CSS do, but is a [native (HTML5) DOM feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.querySelectorAll) :-) Needs to be shimmed in older browsers, though. By "selecting the a tag" you mean "a tags that have a img child"? You could select all `a > img` and then pluck the `.parentNode`s

Comment: You could indeed do that if it was the direct parent. But if it weren't?

Comment: You may well find that if the NodeList returned by *getElementsByClassName* is large, looping over it will be much faster in some browsers (and only marginally slower in others) if it's converted to a static array first.

Comment: If you are looking for A elements, you might instead use the [*document.links*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/dom.html#dom-document-links) collection, which is all the links in a page and is availble as a property in all browsers.